# How to get these json nested values using angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have this json response:

```
 {
  "tags": [
    {
      "name": "SolarData",
      "results": [
        {
          "groups": [
            {
              "name": "type",
              "type": "number"
            }
          ],
          "attributes": {
            "customer": [
              "Acme"
            ],
            "host": [
              "server1"
            ]
          },
          "values": [
            [
              1429950000000,
              46,
              3
            ],
            [
              1429960000000,
              62,
              3
            ],
            [
              1429970000000,
              183,
              3
            ],
            [
              1429980000000,
              156,
              3
            ],
            [
              1429990000000,
              205,
              3
            ]
          ]
        }
      ],
      "stats": {
        "rawCount": 5
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

and I want to be able to only get the first two items of every value part of the item. Foe example I want to return [[1429950000000,46],[1429960000000,62],[1429970000000,183],.....] in a scope variable so I can eventually use it for a graph. I am new to angular and web dev in general but this is the way I've tried it so far.

```
$http({
           url: 'file.json',
           method: 'POST',    
           data: '(query data here)'
         }).then(function(data, status){
            $scope.solarData = data.tags.results.values;
            conosle.log($scope.solarData);
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
var custom = data.tags[0].results[0].values.map(function(values) {
  return [values[0], values[1]];
});
```

You can use [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) if you want to return a lot of items or a variable number of them like

```
return values.slice(0, 2);
//---------------------^ replace this
```

```js
var data = {
  "tags": [{
    "name": "SolarData",
    "results": [{
      "groups": [{
        "name": "type",
        "type": "number"
      }],
      "attributes": {
        "customer": [
          "Acme"
        ],
        "host": [
          "server1"
        ]
      },
      "values": [
        [
          1429950000000,
          46,
          3
        ],
        [
          1429960000000,
          62,
          3
        ],
        [
          1429970000000,
          183,
          3
        ],
        [
          1429980000000,
          156,
          3
        ],
        [
          1429990000000,
          205,
          3
        ]
      ]
    }],
    "stats": {
      "rawCount": 5
    }
  }]
}

var custom = data.tags[0].results[0].values.map(function(values) {
  return [values[0], values[1]];
});
console.log(custom);
```

Comment: Nice'n clean. Though I wonder if `return [values[0], values[1]]` could be faster. (The difference is probably negligible, any way)

Comment: @Cerbrus that's correct it'll be faster since it avoids a function invocation.

Comment: Tried this method and I keep getting a "Cannot read property '0' of undefined" at tags[0] error.

Comment: @KrustyCheerio It works with the same data you posted... maybe you're getting different data in which there is no tags array?

Comment: Changed it to data.data.tags[0].results[0].values.map.... And it worked perfect! Thanks your your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
var requirementArray = new Array();
for (i = 0; i < $scope.solarData.length ; i++) {
    var pare = new Array();
    pare.push($scope.solarData[i][0]);
    pare.push($scope.solarData[i][1]);

    requirementArray.push(pare);
}
```

requirementArray  will be :

[[1429950000000,46],[1429960000000,62],[1429970000000,183],.....]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for that:

```
$http({
   url: 'file.json',
   method: 'POST',    
   data: '(query data here)'
 }).then(function(data, status){
    $scope.solarData = data.tags[0].results[0].values.map(
        function(curVal, index, arr) {
            return [curVal[0], curVal[1]];
        }
    );

    conosle.log($scope.solarData);
});
```

Comment: Why did you add the `index, arr` and `status` parameters if you don't use them?

Comment: @Cerbrus For the clarity of the example, in case he doesn't read the documentation about the function, now op still knows the parameters exist

Comment: And how would he know what `status` means without reading the docs? `index` and `arr` are a little more self-explanatory, but you'd be better off linking to documentation.

Comment: @Cerbrus I just copied that from his own example

Comment: Ah, didn't check that.